# "zscore" function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I saw this `z = zscore(x,0,2)` online, I want to know what the "0" and "2" represent? Which decide the value of "0" and "2"? and if I use `z = zscore(x,0,4)`,does that mean it will more likely generate NaN value in the future 
calculation? Thank you so much!

Comment: From the [`zscore` documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html): "`Z = zscore(X, flag, dim)` [standardizes X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) along dimension *dim*. For example, for a matrix *X*, if *dim* = 1, then zscore uses the means and standard deviations along the columns of *X*, if *dim* = 2, then zscore uses the means and standard deviations along the rows of *X*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab docs are [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html;jsessionid=17874e29d2656a932613845035e6?refresh=true)

From there :

> zscore(X,flag,dim)
>
> If flag is 0 (default), then zscore scales X using the sample standard deviation...
>
> If flag is 1, then zscore scales X using the population standard deviation
>
> zscore(X,flag,dim) standardizes X along dimension dim

You wouldn't change the 2 to a 4 unless the dimensions of the data changed.

Comment: usually, it is better to use sample standard deviation or it is better to use population standard deviation? which one will more likely cause NaN value?

Comment: NaN is likely to be caused by dividing by zero. Have you checked X? Are you sure that the SD is non-zer0 ?